# How to use uniq if lines have the same strings in the middle?

Tags: sorting, unix, awk

I am new to unix and would like to be able to do the following but am unsure how.

Take a text file with lines like:

```
pt832p41iEC.213631_EDI832I140401232501.txt 
pt832p41iEC.213632_EDI832I140401232502.txt 
se832p41iEC.200289_EDI832I140401232506.txt 
se832p41iEC.200289_EDI832I140401232507.txt 
xe832p41iEC.201687_EDI832I140401232511.txt 
xe832p41iEC.201687_EDI832I140401232512.txt
```

If there are duplicate session number, it should extract the first occurrence.
And output this:

```
pt832p41iEC.213631_EDI832I140401232501.txt
pt832p41iEC.213632_EDI832I140401232502.txt  
se832p41iEC.200289_EDI832I140401232506.txt  
xe832p41iEC.201687_EDI832I140401232511.txt
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please be explicit about which part of the filename is the session number. I am guessing it is the first part, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @user3491651 You can considering marking anyone of the following answer if it helped to resolve your question. That would let everyone know your issue has been resolved. It will give you some reps too so that you can vote up on answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using awk if $1 and $2 are not always paired.

```
awk -F"[._]" '!a[$2]++' file
```

Comment: Thanks @BMW, will try your code in few moment and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk -F"_" '!seen[$1]++' file
pt832p41iEC.213631_EDI832I140401232501.txt
pt832p41iEC.213632_EDI832I140401232502.txt
se832p41iEC.200289_EDI832I140401232506.txt
xe832p41iEC.201687_EDI832I140401232511.txt
```

This solution is an `awk` idiom which basically means:

```
awk '!($1 in seen) {seen[$1]++;print}' file
```

Comment: This works only for duplicate lines next to each other. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @user3491651 No it will find duplicates on any lines will always report the first one. If you ran it and found the behaviour you just reported then it is highly possible that you input file has leading spaces. Nonetheless I'm glad you found your solution.